# How to handle a map of shared_ptr with move constructor correctly?

Tags: c++, dictionary, shared-ptr

Consider I have a container `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>` and I want to fill it in external function and avoid coping of its contents. So I have

```
typedef Container std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>

Container&& f(){
    Container bar;
    auto foo = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass());
    bar.insert(std::make_pair(0,foo));
    std::cout<<bar.at(1)->print_smth<<'\n'; //This works
    return std::move(bar);
}

int main(){
    Container baz(f());
    std::cout<<bar.at(1)->print_smth<<'\n'; //This doesn't
    // Container baz has element 1, but shared_ptr is invalidated, because it has 0 references.

}
```

If I use conventional copy constructor everything works as expected.

Comment: A return value already is an rvalue, and there will be most likely no copy done due to RVO.

Comment: You must not return a reference to a local, automatic object. It's undefined behaviour to access that reference.

Comment: @Cubic in practice with a modern compiler an optimization enabled you are correct, but I stiil don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @galadog: `bar` is destroyed when you return from `f()`, so the reference to return doesn't refer to a valid object. Hence undefined behaviour. And even if the optimisation fails for some reason, a returned value will be moved not copied.

Comment: @KerrekSB so, how should I handle this? If I create a container with pointers evething will work, but I will loose all features of shared_ptr.

Comment: @galadog: Return by value. It won't be copied.

Comment: @galadog: Return by value. You have no choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *far* too complicated. Why not just say this:

```
int main()
{
    Container baz { { 0, std::make_shared<MyClass>() } };

    // ...
}
```

If you absolutely must go with the helper function, you have to return an object, not a dangling reference. Something like this:

```
Container f()
{
    return Container { { 0, std::make_shared<MyClass>() } };
}
```

It's hard to indulge anything more pedestrian than this, but one final, never-to-be-used-at-home version:

```
Container f()
{
   Container bar;
   auto p = std::make_shared<MyClass>;

   bar[0] = p;                        // Method #1
   // ---- ALTERNATIVELY ---
   bar.insert(std::make_pair(0, p));  // Method #2
   // ---- ALTERNATIVELY ---
   bar.emplace(0, p);                 // Method #3

   return bar;
}
```

Comment: Of course I simplified my code before posting here. Helper function is  much bigger. But what difference with my code second and third example?

Comment: @galadog: 1) the return type, 2) the return statement, 3) the creation of the shared pointer.

Comment: @galadog: Your code returns by reference, this code returns by value. This means that your code ends up using an object after it has been destroyed (and thus having UB), where this code does not.

Comment: @Mankarse: A subtle point is that `return bar;` allows for RVO, while `return std::move(bar);` actually *inhibits* RVO.

Comment: @KerrekSB, as I pointed in my question, copy constructor works. My question is how to avoid coping content of Container?

Comment: @galadog: There should never be a copy constructor called in the above code (as long as your objects all have move constructors). Either the copy will be elided, object will be moved out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a reference from your `f()`. An rvalue reference is still a reference and just like you would never return a reference to a local from a function you can't do that with rvalue references either.

The good news is that you don't have to. Thanks to the [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) you can simply return a `Container` from `f()` and it will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you mean "lvalue"? :-(